# An Arbitrary Open Set can be Expressed as a Countable Union of Compact Sets

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question with reference to Lemma $A.5$ in the book ''From Calculus to Cohomology", the statement of which is as follows:

**Any arbitrary open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be written in the form $U=\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} K_{m}$, where for each $m\geq 1$, $K_{m}$ is compact, and $K_{m}\subseteq K_{m+1}^{\bullet}$, where $X^{\bullet}$ denotes the interior of $X$.**

My questions are two-fold:

1. It is known that a countable union of compact (hence closed) sets is not necessarily an open set. So, how is the equation $U=\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} K_{m}$ justified in the Lemma, with $U$ being open and the RHS not necessarily known to be open?
2. What is the purpose of choosing the interior of the set in the equation $K_{m}\subseteq K_{m+1}^{\bullet}$?

Can somebody please throw light on these points and correct me if my argument is false?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Not necessarily" does not mean "always". Take, e.g., $K_n = [1/n,1-1/n]$. Then $\bigcup_n K_n = (0,1)$.
2. It ensures that $K_{n+1}$ is in some sense strictly larger than $K_n$. There is a positive distance between $K_n$ and the boundary of $K_{n+1}$.